# Regex behaves differently depending on client

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have this app in node.js. A user uploads a pdf and the server needs to modify the client's filename to only contain alphanumeric characters plus some other character (colon and dot).

The code is then the following:

```
console.log('document.fileName:',document.fileName);
var temp = document.fileName.replace(/[^\w.:-]+/g, "");
console.log('temp:',temp);
```

Now, opening the frontend (in angular) with my Mac and using Chrome, I upload the file with the name

```
åäö&23^¨testarkönstigatäcken
```

I can see in the log on the server:

```
document.fileName: åäö&23^¨testarkönstigatäcken
temp: aao23testarkonstigatacken
```

As you can see, it replaced "äåö" with "aao". The other non alphanumerical characters were removed.

But, if I do the same thing with Safari browser "äåö" will be stripped away. With this result in the log:

```
document.fileName: åäö&23^¨testarkönstigatäcken
temp: 23testarknstigatcken
```

When doing the same thing in Firefox I got the same result as with Chrome, with regex keeping the "äåö".

When I do the same in windows, no matter what browser, non alphanumeric are stripped away and are not being replaced.

So, what I wonder is how it is possible that this regex on the server is dependent on client environment.
Because in all the cases, it received the same filename. But it acts differently depending on what client made the request.

Comment: Try testing what `String.fromCharCode.apply(null, Array.from(function* () { for (let i = 0; i < 0x10000; ++i) { yield i } }())).match(/\w+/g)` does on your various clients.  That should tell you which (basic plane) characters are treated as word characters.

Comment: Are your filenames in the same [normal form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) regardless of client?  If not, they may show as the same in the console, but have different characters even if you've got no encoding problems.

Comment: Does the document have an explicit encoding, such as UTF-8?

Comment: Mike, Im not sure about your posting (what you want to accomplish). YELD in nodejs? Nothing happened so I replaces it with console.log. And I only saw numbers being printed, fro 1 to 65535.

Comment: Had a look at the file properties. Nothing about formatting. Only that it has been produced by Word (I guess exported word file that became pdf).

Comment: Tried normalize(). In both browsers (one that fails and one that succeds) the string is exactly the same.

Comment: @oderfla, I get `["0123456789", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "_", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]`.  Are you using an older Node?

Comment: I think @ArndtJonasson is asking about the encoding of the upload request, not any encoding metadata present in the uploaded PDF.

Comment: Im using v8.6.0

Comment: I cannot see any specific about encoding during the request. I see "multipart/form-data" as content-type and gzip, deflate as accepted encoding.

Comment: @MikeSamuel what node version are you using?

Comment: @oderfla v8.9.4.  The code snippet also works on v9.11.0, v7.10.1, and v6.14.1 which is what npx gives me.  I run `npx node@6` at the command line which gives me a REPL, then I paste in the command and it pretty prints an array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to normalize the string before you feed it regex.

[normalize-strings/normalize.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize-strings) makes this easy:

```
var n = require('normalize');
console.log(n('Åland')) // Aland
```

I hope this helps.